# Question about a question about approaching work-related stay in Australia

Tags: discussion, expat-questions, best-practices

My company is doing a project with a big customer in Australia, which spans several years. The customer also works on the same project. My employer and I discussed me going over there for a year with my partner and there are a lot of visa/travel scenarios possible.

I have a concise question about this, but before posting would like to know if this is the right place for it, or if there are any best practices to be aware of.

(PS I couldn't find a meta meta travel StackExchange to ask if this question here is appropriate)

Comment: Expats.SE is probably better suited (https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MarkMayo I spend so much time on SE, though no idea this existed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you gonna stay for a year, most likely you will need a long term work visa, open a bank account, etc.

I suggest asking that in [expats.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).